# Eclipse RCP - Custom FilteredPreferenceDialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to implement a custom preference dialog using the **FilteredPreferenceDialog** class.

The problem that this is an abstract class, but I dont really understand why. It has no abstract methods. I created my own class which extends **FilteredPreferenceDialog** but then I get the discouraged access warnings. There is another class called **WorkbenchPreferenceDialog** which also extends **FilteredPreferenceDialog**, and its also abstract.

Is there a class which is a public not abstract class I can create which has the filtering implementation? The **PreferenceDialog** class works fine except it doesnt have the filtering mechanism.

Comment: Both these classes are **internal** and should not be used - see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html). Unfortunately there is no usable filtered preference dialog.

Comment: It is possible to use the normal preference dialog to show a subset of the preferences - would that do what you want?

Comment: I think the problem is that I wanted to use the functionality that there is now, and the users also expect that. But our preferences are custom made completely loaded from a web service, so I cant use the original eclipse functionality either.